Infinite integer powers of odd primes multiplying to 2
Is there a(n infinite) sequence of integer numbers $x_k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_k}^{x_k} = 2$$
where $p_1, p_2, p_3...$ are all the primes excluding $p_0 = 2$?
In other words, I'm looking for a sequence of powers of primes, including negative ones, that would multiply to 2, but I don't want to use 2 itself (and that would be trivial btw).
Can such a fraction of infinite products converge to 2?
$$ \frac{3^{m_1}\cdot 5^{m_2}\cdot 7^{m_3}\cdot 11^{m_4}\cdot ...}{3^{n_1}\cdot 5^{n_2}\cdot 7^{n_3}\cdot 11^{n_4}\cdot ...} \to 2,$$
$m_k, n_k\in\mathbb{N}$
Finite product $ \frac{3\cdot 7}{11} $ generated by $ (1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0,...) $ gets quite close to 2, so I have a feeling the gap could be made arbitrarily small. Am I wrong?
Whether it's possible or not, can you explain how to show it? What books/materials/anything should I get to know?
I'd love to know how to generate explicit sequence $x_k$, but non-constructive proof would be fine, too.

If an inf8mite product converges, the terms must converge to $1$. The only way for these terms to converge to $1$ is if only finitely many $x_k$ are non-zero.

If all exponents are $0$ , the product is $1$. If there is a positive exponent , we get an odd number greater than $1$ , if the product is finite at all (see the above comment). Hence , to get $2$ , is impossible.

Of course , we can get arbitary close to $2$ , if also negative exponents are allowed. Just use the factorizations of $2n+1$ and $n$ for some large $n$

@Peter, negative exponents are allowed. Are you sure we can get as close to 2 as we wish? Wouldn't that be convergence and hence contradiction with the accepted answer? Or do I misunderstand you?

My previous comment did not consider the possibility of negative exponents. I cannot rule out that for some sequence $x_i$ , the product converges to $2$. This is however only possible , if there are infinite many non-zero exponents , so neither the numerator nor the denominator is finite. Otherwise we have a rational number with odd numerator and odd denominator and then , $2$ is obviously impossible.

I wish you were right, @Peter, but it seems that the necessary condition for the infinite product to converge is that its terms converge to 1.

Anyway , it is possible to get arbitary close to $2$. But I think Thomas Andrews is right , but if we merge two factors (infinite often) , the situation changes because then the sequence can converge to $1$.

If the product converges, then $\lim_{k\to\infty}{p_k}^{x_k}=1$ so for all sufficiently large $k$, $x_k=0$. Then use the Fundemental theorem of Arithmetic to show a finite product cannot be $2$.

But also, if we let the powers to be rational ($x_k\in\mathbb{Q}$), would that change the answer? With very small non-zero powers the terms can converge to 1, right?

With rational powers the answer is yes. $5^{1/100}$ is close to $1.$ Do something similar for the other prime numbers. Then multiply these numbers just greater than $1$ together. We should be able to get $2.$

An interesting related question is whether there is a sequence $p_1^{n_1} p_2^{n_2}\cdots p_i^{n_i}$ with a subsequence converging, say, to $2$.  Here $(p_i)$ is the enumeration of all odd primes whereas $n_i\in\mathbb Z$.

The original question,

Is there a(n infinite) sequence of integer numbers $x_k\in\mathbb{Z}$
such that $$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_k}^{x_k} = 2$$ where $p_1, p_2,
 p_3...$ are all the primes excluding $p_0 = 2$?

has already been answered. However, if you change the question to:

Are there four subsequences of integers $a_k,b_k,c_k,d_k\in\mathbb{Z},\ $
such that $$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{{p_{a_k}}^{b_k}}{{p_{c_k}}^{d_k}} = 2$$ where $p_1, p_2,
 p_3...$ are all the primes excluding $p_0 = 2$?

The I'm quite sure the answer is yes, and it works for $b_k=d_k=1$ for all $k,$ and we can show it to be true using the prime number theorem.

Edit:
Let me explain what precisely is meant by the expression,
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_k}^{x_k},$$
as without precisely defining what this means, it could mean any number of things. The standard definition is given as follows.
To make the explanation easier, first define, for each $n\in\mathbb{N},\ r_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}^{x_k}.$
Then $r_n$ is a sequence of rational numbers (each number is the result of a finite product). In particular,
$r_1=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{1}{p_k}^{x_k} = {p_1}^{x_1}.$
$r_2=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{2}{p_k}^{x_k} = {p_1}^{x_1}{p_2}^{x_2}.$
$r_3=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{3}{p_k}^{x_k} = {p_1}^{x_1}{p_2}^{x_2}{p_3}^{x_3}.$
And so on.
You can even call this a sequence of partial products, similar to how an infinite series, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y_n,$ is really just a sequence of partial sums.
What
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_k}^{x_k}$$
means, is, if it exists, the limit of the sequence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} r_n.$$
where the definition of a limit of a sequence of real numbers is given here.
If $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} r_n$ does not exist, then this is the same as saying $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_k}^{x_k}$ does not exist.
The reason we cannot have $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{p_k}^{x_k} = 2$ where $p_1, p_2,
 p_3...$ are all the primes has already been explained in an answer.

But,
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{{p_{a_k}}^{b_k}}{{p_{c_k}}^{d_k}}$$
means the limit of the sequence of partial products,
$\prod_{k=1}^{1} \frac{{p_{a_k}}^{b_k}}{{p_{c_k}}^{d_k}},\ \prod_{k=1}^{2} \frac{{p_{a_k}}^{b_k}}{{p_{c_k}}^{d_k}},\ \prod_{k=1}^{3} \frac{{p_{a_k}}^{b_k}}{{p_{c_k}}^{d_k}},\ \ldots,$
i.e., the limit of the sequence,
$\frac{{p_{a_1}}^{b_1}}{{p_{c_1}}^{d_1}},\ \frac{{p_{a_1}}^{b_1}}{{p_{c_1}}^{d_1}}\frac{{p_{a_2}}^{b_2}}{{p_{c_2}}^{d_2}},\ \frac{{p_{a_1}}^{b_1}}{{p_{c_1}}^{d_1}}\frac{{p_{a_2}}^{b_2}}{{p_{c_2}}^{d_2}}\frac{{p_{a_3}}^{b_3}}{{p_{c_3}}^{d_3}}.$
This can be made to converge to $2,$ for example, something like,
$$\left(\frac{5}{3}\right),\ \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\left(\frac{13}{11}\right),\ \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\left(\frac{13}{11}\right)\left(\frac{1301}{1283}\right),$$
although I chose sort of random prime numbers here. I just think the PNT should guarantee us success here, due to the properties of $\frac{n}{\log n}.$ (I think concavity and derivative tending to zero are the key properties).

Since $b_k=d_k=1$, then how is $\prod\frac{p_{a_k}}{p_{c_k}}$ different from the original? All the primes not included in the sequence get 0s in the main sequence and primes in the denominator get negative powers. Is it about the order of operations in the infinite product? We first divide prime powers and then multiply the results, allowing the terms to converge to 1?

@AdHoc, I think the confusion comes from not knowing the precise definition of infinite products. I have updated my answer to go into more detail. Yes it is sort of about the order of operations. More like, it's about the fact that an infinite product is really a sequence of partial products, which is in fact, just a sequence of real numbers. So you have to think, "what are the numbers in my sequence?"

So $\lim_{n\to\infty} r_n$ cannot equal 2, but, using your latter construction, by suitably defining the $n_j$, there is an increasing sequence $(n_j)$ where $\lim_{j\to\infty} r_{n_j}=2$, right?

@AdamRubinson The OP used $x$ for a sequence (of exponents). I noticed that you were using $x$ for the same sequence, and for a second sequence as well. So I changed $x$ to $r$ for that second sequence.

@RosieF Yes that's correct.
